# Change Y-axis label VB:net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, charts, axis-labels

I have a program that renders a chart that calculates the time of a work day.
It shows only 3 days ahead, and shows the numbers in percent.

Some thing like this:

```
400-|-----------------------------------
    |
300-|-----------------------------------
    |    |  55% |
200-|----------------------------------- 
    |    | 100% |       |  98% |
100-|----------------------------------- 
    |    | 100% |       | 100% |
0---|----------------------------------- 
    |    STATION 1      STATION 2
```

This data tells me that station 1 has 100% to do day 1 & 2 and only 55% of work 3 days from now. What i would like to change here, is just the Y-axis labels to "Day" with numbers. Something like this:

```
Day 4-|-----------------------------------
      |
Day 3-|-----------------------------------
      |    |  55% |
Day 2-|----------------------------------- 
      |    | 100% |       |  98% |
Day 1-|----------------------------------- 
      |    | 100% |       | 100% |
----0-|----------------------------------- 
      |    STATION 1      STATION 2
```

How can i do this? I guess something like

```
For Each YAxis in TheChart
    YAxis.Label = "Day " & YAxis.Label / 100
End For
```

How do i do this more specific, or is there any other way?
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well im thinking you are using text. To do this you would first declare a variable called C1:

```
Dim C1 = [label that contains the number]/100.
```

repeate this with c2 c3 and c4.

Use the variables in the labels.

I did not really understand your question. So i may be way off as to what you're asking.